# jQuery changing style of HTML element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list on HTML

```
<div id="header" class="row">
    <div id="logo" class="col_12">And the winner is<span>n't...</span></div> 
    <div id="navigation" class="row"> 
        <ul id="pirra">
            <li><a href="#">Why?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Synopsis</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stills/Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Videos/clips</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Quotes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Quiz</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

it changes fine to show horizontally on CSS change

```
div#navigation ul li { 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

but now I want to do it with jQuery, I use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('hello');
    $('#navigation ul li').css('display': 'inline-block');
});
```

but is not working, What do i have wrong to style my element with jQuery?

thanks

Comment: The problem was caused by a typo. Arguments in JavaScript function calls are separated with `,` not `:`.

Comment: Good question...:)

Answer (score 289, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('#navigation ul li').css('display', 'inline-block');
```

Also, as others have stated, if you want to make multiple css changes at once, that's when you would add the curly braces (for object notation), and it would look something like this (if you wanted to change, say, 'background-color' and 'position' in addition to 'display'):

```
$('#navigation ul li').css({'display': 'inline-block', 'background-color': '#fff', 'position': 'relative'}); //The specific CSS changes after the first one, are, of course, just examples.
```

Comment: or: `$('#navigation ul li').css({'display': 'inline-block'});` - I constantly mix those two up.

Comment: @Blazemonger LOL, I didn't even know you could do that, but now that you mention it, that 'does' make sense. Thanks for broadening my horizons here.

Comment: Seems better to memorize the curly braced version then, since it can adapt to one or more attributes at a time with the same syntax ;)

Comment: camel case also works so you can use .css({backgroundColor: "#fff"}) - PS i hate double quotes but they are easier to see in this comment

Answer (score 23):

```
$('#navigation ul li').css('display', 'inline-block');
```

not a colon, a comma

Answer (score 15):

```
$('#navigation ul li').css({'display' : 'inline-block'});
```

It seems a typo there ...syntax mistake  :))

Answer (score 6):

you could also specify multiple style values like this

```
$('#navigation ul li').css({'display': 'inline-block','background-color': '#ff0000', 'color': '#ffffff'});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use this code also:
and you can manage your class css better

```
<style>
   .navigationClass{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 6px;
        background-color: whitesmoke;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }
</style>
<div id="header" class="row">
    <div id="logo" class="col_12">And the winner is<span>n't...</span></div> 
    <div id="navigation" class="row"> 
        <ul id="pirra">
            <li><a href="#">Why?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Synopsis</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stills/Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Videos/clips</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Quotes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Quiz</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('#navigation ul li').addClass('navigationClass'); //add class navigationClass to the #navigation .

});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

changing style with jquery

**Try This**

```
$('#selector_id').css('display','none');
```

You can also change multiple attribute in a single query

Try This

```
$('#replace-div').css({'padding-top': '5px' , 'margin' : '10px'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the second element inside a `<div>` with an specific **id** and change the style:

```
var post_id = 7;
var heart = $('#' + post_id).children().eq(1);
heart.css('color','red');
```

**Note:** This may seem obvious but it troubled me and may also happen to you. Make sure the style you want to modify *is of the div itself* and not a *style inside that div*. So for example you may have something like:

```
<div class="loves_it"><i class="fas fa-heart" style="color:gray"></i></div>
```

And abviously `css()` method of Jquery won't work. So make sure it's as follows:

```
<div class="loves_it" style="color:gray"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></div>
```