# How to add style attributes+values to a certain (unknown) class?

Tags: jquery, styles, assign

Assume I have the following html/CSS code:

```
<div .......>
<div class="....." ....>            
....foobar ....
</div>
</div>
```

I can reference the closest  element which contains "foobar" as follows:

```
$("div:contains('foobar')").closest("div");
```

Now I want to change the font-size and line-height for this  element.
...and possible overwrite existing font-size and line-height values;

How can I achieve this in jQuery?

Something like

```
$("div:contains('foobar')").closest("div").style.fontSize("16px !important").lineHeight("18px !important");
```

....seems not to work;

See description above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery changing style of HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086201/jquery-changing-style-of-html-element)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("div:contains('foobar')").closest("div").css({'font-size':'16px','line-height':'18px'});
```